# Solution of Burger equation by Newton-Raphson method in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pde

I am solving Burger equation with Newton-Raphson method in Mathlab.
For the description of the problem see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kon4l.jpg).

My problem is the following this code finds the solution upto time 
$t=1$, but at this time a discontinuity develops and then the wave 
moves forward (like a step function), but this code does not produce 
correct solutions after time $t=1$.

Any suggestions or comments to improve the code.

Here is the Matlab code that I am using

```
function BurgerFSolve2
clc; clear;
% define a 1D mesh
a = -1; b = 3; Nx = 100;
x = linspace(a,b,Nx);
dx = (b-a)/Nx;
J = length(x); 

% Iinitial condition
p_init = zeros(size(x));
p_init(x<=0) = 1;
p_init(x>0 & x<1)= 1-x(x>0 & x<1);

% storing results
P = zeros(length(p_init),3001);
P(:,1) = p_init; 
% Boundary condition
pL = 1; pR = 0;  

% solver
dt = 0.001;
t = 0;
T = zeros(1,3001);
c = dt/dx;
for i = 1:3000
    t = t+dt;
    T(i+1) = t;

    options=optimset('Display','iter');   % Option to display output
    p = fsolve(@(p) myfun1(p, pL, pR, c, J, P(:,i)), p_init, ...
    options);         
    % Call solver 
    P(:,i+1) = p;
    p_init = p;

    figure(1);
    plot(x, p, '-o'); 
    title(['t= ' num2str(t) ' s']);
    drawnow;
end
end 

function F = myfun1(p, pL, pR, c, J, p_Old) 
% Rewrite the equation in the form F(x) = 0
F(1) = p(1) + c*(p(1)^2 - p(1)*pL) - p_Old(1);
for i=2:J-1 
    F(i) = p(i) + c*(p(i)^2 - p(i-1)*p(i)) - p_Old(i);
end
F(J) = p(J)  + c*(p(J)^2 - p(J-1)*p(J)) - p_Old(J);
end
```

Comment: You get a singularity at `t=0`, maybe have a look at R. LeVeque's [Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Numerical_Methods_for_Conservation_Laws.html?id=UvmpBwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y&hl=en)

Comment: @Steve Singularity develops at t=1, until this time code works well, but for time greater than 1, it does not, that is where I am stuck.

Comment: Yes, for inviscid Burgers' equation, if you use the method of characteristics you'll see that the characteristics cross and you get multiple solutions for some `x`, or you can treat it as a shock (a jump in the solution, check the [Rankine-Hugoniot condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine%E2%80%93Hugoniot_conditions)) . If you want a solution past this point you could use some form of shock-tracking algorithm, or you might be able to make some progress with a consevative solver. There's no quick fix

Comment: You might be able to get a better solution by considering `p*(p_x) = (p^2/2)_x` where `p_x` in the derivative of `p` with respect to `x`.